# VBA Dictionary add fails in reading Excel sheet headings unless I use Trim

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, trim

```
Function getHeaderRowDict(sht)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, dict As New Dictionary, i As Long
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        dict(Trim(rng.Cells(1, i))) = i
    Next
    Set getHeaderRowDict = dict
End Function
```

I have used this short code to read cells from the first row of currentRange of a sheet to use as a sort of Enum in later code. e.g dict("ID") to return the column number of the column headed with text "ID".If the Trim function is left out and it really has no business or need to be there the Dictionary is returned with all values empty. Leaving Trim() in gives the expected result. Explain why please!

Comment: In VBA, if you pass the cell value without it, it's passed as a reference, which messes things up - it has to be a literal string value - the same thing can be accomplished by declaring a string variable, setting it to the cell value without the trim, and then adding that to the dictionary.

Comment: `dict(rng.Cells(i).Value) = i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Dictionary docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

> The key is used to retrieve an individual item and is usually an integer
> or a string, but can be anything except an array.

So you have to be careful how you add your keys.  For example using a row with some headers "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", Green"

```vba
Sub Tester()
    Dim d, k
    
    'without trim
    Set d = getHeaderRowDict(ActiveSheet)
    For Each k In d
        Debug.Print k, TypeName(k), d(k)
    Next k
'Keys and values look OK, but keys are actually Range objects
'    Red           Range          1
'    Yellow        Range          2
'    Blue          Range          3
'    Green         Range          4
    
    Debug.Print "Red = ", d("Red") '...but not really working

'   Red =
    
    'now using Trim()
    Set d = getHeaderRowDictV2(ActiveSheet)
    For Each k In d
        Debug.Print k, TypeName(k), d(k)
    Next k

'Now we have String-type keys
'   Red           String         1
'   Yellow        String         2
'   Blue          String         3
'   Green         String         4

   Debug.Print "Red = ", d("Red") 'this does work

'  Red =          1

End Sub

Function getHeaderRowDict(sht)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, dict As New Dictionary, i As Long
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        dict(rng.Cells(i)) = i
    Next
    Set getHeaderRowDict = dict
End Function

Function getHeaderRowDictV2(sht)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, dict As New Dictionary, i As Long
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        dict(Trim(rng.Cells(i))) = i '<< added trim, but .Value would also work
    Next
    Set getHeaderRowDictV2 = dict
End Function
```

...another reason to get in the habit of always using `.Value` instead of relying on the default property.

Comment: I haven't used SO for some time and now appears comments are not for saying thank you but simply for clarication and pointing out problems. So let me just clarify that I am very grateful for time taken by those who responded with both detailed and succinct analyis to answer my question.  I don't see any buttons to click for thanks so maybe that is a problem with the posts that could be addressed with further advice?

Comment: You can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: I hadn't twigged that Trim does more than remove whitespace. It clearly converts ranges to text when needed so I now grasp why what was a wild guess to use Trim actualy works. As pointed out .Value is by far the better option and I will now adopt that disciplne rather than rely on the default property.